# Shuffle Function Complexity

Tags: java, random, hashmap, complexity-theory, big-o

I am trying to figure out the complexity of the function below. I am guessing it would be O(n), because the Random class produces a random number in O(1) and put() and `containsKey()` are also O(1).

But since there is a `do-while` inside the loop, I wasn't sure if the complexity would change since random() could be called multiple times if the value is contained in the HashMap. I would appreciate any help!

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> values = new HashMap();
for(int i=0 ; i<a.length; i++){
    do{
        // set variable random to some integer between 0 and a.length using Random class in Java, 0 is included. 
    }while(values.containsKey(random) == true);
    b[i] = a[random]
    values.put(random,0);
}
```

The length of the array is around 1000 and the random number generated is anywhere from 0 to 999.

Comment: Ofcoure if α is very small and it approaches to O(n). What about collisions?

Comment: Finding the random value that your map doesnot have is O(n)

Comment: Think of the range of random-integers and your map size. Lets say it is 4/3--->then finding non-existent random will be %66-->doing this for every new element will build up O(n) (we can neglect O(1) of hashmap lookup)

Comment: Updated the answer but couldn find logn . Where did you think logn came from?

Comment: Never mind, I think your right. The complexity would probably become n^2. What algorithm could I use to shuffle a sorted array with a lower complexity than this ?

Comment: I think yours is thhe fastest for 1000 randoms to 1000 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Building the map elements: O(n)--->for loop

 Checking if the random value is in the map: O(1+α) with a good hash function
 Trying to find a random value which your map does not have: O(n)
 (because you are using integer. Even floats would give very good resolution)


 array length=1000, random-value range=1000(from 0 to 999)
 think you are at the last element. probability of getting proper value is:
 %0.1 which takes an average of 1000 trials only for the last element (n)
 nearly same for the (n-1)st element (%0.2-->n/2 trials)
 still nearly same for (n-2)nd element (%0.3-->n/3 trials)

 what is n+n/2 + n/3 + n/4 + n/5  ... + 1 = a linear function(O(n)) +1 
 α2=1 but neglecting :) and this is on top of a O(n)


 Result: O(n*n+α*n*n) close to O(n*n)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying. Do you mean its O(n^2) ? finding a random value inside the HashMap shouldnt take O(n) because the the containsKey method is O(1)

Comment: How are you handling the collisions?

Comment: Well I dont think I would have collisions. Becuase the key I am adding is the index of the array. And I can be certain that there will not be any duplicates. If values.containsKey(random) is true then i wont add that index to the HashMap. So I am never adding the same Key twice.

Comment: Checking if the new random value is in array would make O(n) what do you think?

Comment: I've added the length of the array and the range of random nos. I agree that complexity would increase to check if the number generated is not in the HashMap, but I expected it to be around O(nlogn)